# how to add one day in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format in python?

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have this string '2019-01-11', in year-month-day , i want to add one day to this date, and convert it into date format in python.

i tried to convert it to date format, so that i can add one day to it by using 'timedelta' class.

```
date_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-01-11', "%y-%m-%d")
date_1 =date_1 + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

but i got this error line 1.

```
raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '2019-01-11' does not match format '%y-%m-%d'
```

Comment: check out https://strftime.org/ - it takes you less time to find out that you need `%Y` instead of `%y` than you need to write this question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The format you're after is:

```
date_1 = datetime.strptime('2019-01-11', "%Y-%m-%d")
```

(upper case "Y")

Answer (score 0):

A four-digit year is `%Y`.  See the doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-01-11', "%Y-%m-%d") + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 12, 0, 0)
```

Note also that you have a couple of typos in your original code -- the first line has a random semicolon at the end, and the second line references `date1` instead of `date_1`.

Answer (score 0):

For the past 5 years, I've been using pandas [Timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) and [Timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) for everything date related. Once something is in Timestamp format, it can be exported as a datetime:

```
In[1]:  from pandas import Timestamp, Timedelta
In[2]:  x=Timestamp("2022-10-31") + Timedelta(1, unit="days"))
In[3]:  x=x.date()
Out[3]: datetime.date(2022, 11, 1)
```

And if it's kept in [Timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) format, it can be printed as a string:

```
In[3]:  x=Timestamp("2022-10-31") + Timedelta(1, unit="days")
In[4]:  f"{x:%Y-%m-%d}"
Out[4]: 2022-11-01
```